# app depends on both audio_recorder ^1.0.2 and build_runner ^2.1.7, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error when I add audio_recorder: ^1.0.2. how to solve this. appreciate your help on this. it doesnt work when I remove numbers infront of audio recorder.

Because build_runner >=1.11.2 depends on glob ^2.0.0 which depends on file ^6.0.0, build_runner >=1.11.2 requires file ^6.0.0.
And because audio_recorder >=0.0.6 depends on file ^5.0.4, build_runner >=1.11.2 is incompatible with audio_recorder >=0.0.6.
So, because doctor_app depends on both audio_recorder ^1.0.2 and build_runner ^2.1.7, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because doctor_app depends on both audio_recorder ^1.0.2 and build_runner ^2.1.7, version solving failed.)

pubspec.yamal

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intro_slider: ^3.0.3
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  animated_theme_switcher: ^2.0.6
  getwidget: ^2.0.4
  get: ^4.6.1
  video_player: ^2.2.18
  dio: ^4.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  #flutter_sound_lite: ^8.5.0
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  
  cupertino_list_tile: ^0.2.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.10
  cloud_functions:
  audio_recorder: ^1.0.2
  

  
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  path_provider:
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: 
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.2.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  
 
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
  json_serializable: ^6.1.4
  video_thumbnail: ^0.4.6
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  shrink_sidemenu: ^2.0.0+2-null-safety
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.9
  flutter_chat_bubble: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
  cloud_firestore: 
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  

  uuid: ^3.0.5

  file_picker: ^4.4.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Audio_recorder is an old package and has been updated 2 years ago. therefore it has some compatibility issues. for recording use flutter_sound pacakge. Here is the link https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound/example